# Why <center> can still work in html 5?

Tags: html

`<!DOCTYPE html>` specifies the page as html 5. But, when I used `<center>`, it can still center the content. Why `<center>` can still work in html 5 as I read from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ that `<center>` is supposed to not work?

Comment: Related: [<center> is not supported in HTML5 but its still working. How?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51728/center-is-not-supported-in-html5-but-its-still-working-how)

Comment: Just a remark: the page you link to doesn't say it's supposed to not work. Oh, and moreover, the page doesn't even mention elements such as `marquee`, `plaintext`, `listing`, `nobr`, `xmp` etc!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tag is obsolete since HTML4. But it is still supported in some browsers even now. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) advices to not use it

> Obsolete
>
> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers,  its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

Use css `text-align: center` instead.

Comment: I do not understand too. Why disable something that works?

Answer (score 0):

It's not part of the specs anymore but it's up to the browser whether or not they still support the tag. Most browsers will to make sure older code still works.

But, since it is deprecated you should not use it in new code. Go with CSS to get your stuff centered.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers may still support it and at some point they will not. Take at look at this page to see if you can use or should use an html element, css property and more: http://caniuse.com/#search=center

Comment: "These elements/tags are obsolete... browser support is not tracked"

Comment: And therefore it should not be used :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML4, `<center>`, and other presentation tags (such as `<blink>`) has been deprecated from HTML specs, and removed in HTML5 specs.
Those tags should be replaced by other content tags (the most abstract one being `<div>`) in addition to CSS for the styling they did provide.

But since those tags don't lead to any security issue, (contrary to `<frame>`) they may still be supported by browsers for compatibility issues.

Even if *today*, [google](https://www.google.com/)'s main page still uses it, you should prefer to use an other content tag with proper CSS styling.